# Flutter connection to Mysql

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-dependencies, mysql-error-1064

my name is Marques and desenvolving a flutter project for my end project in school and i'm a little but desesperated with a error that i can't solve .
I hope someone could help solving this to could continue making my flutter app.

[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCE3I.png)
they are saying that 'The argument type String can't be assigned to the Parameter Uri'

[Adding as Uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj481.png) and making a run of the mobile flutter project when i enter the email and password and click into the Login Button appers the next message to me
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wGZx.png)
I hope someone could help me I will be very grateful

I had tried to change it or to add a similar code but didnt work

Answer (score 3):

```
Uri.parse("http://localhost/tienda/login.php")
```

Instead of using as Uri, try to parse the string with the following way.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way

```
await http.post(Uri.parse("http://localhost/tienda/login.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `post()` method of [http](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html) package expects [Uri](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri-class.html) instead of string.

All you need to do is parse the url string you provided.

```
final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse("http://localhost/tienda/login.php"),
  body: {
    "username": // username,
    "password": // password
  }
);
```